# Bevel not working on text object with boolean

Tags: rendering, modifiers, objects, vertices, text-object

I am facing a problem with a text based object that I am trying to bevel the edges of. Originally it was a solid object, this then had a boolean cut out of it to make the final letterform. It appears the mesh needs edges going across for it to stay a solid face on the top and bottom of the object. So when I select the outer and inner edges of the top and bottom of the object it messes up. If anyone has any idea of how I can bevel these edges probably without the vertices messing up that would be great, thanks!

Here's some images illustrating the problems I am having. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIT7T.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2CU4.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVVOV.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebsN8.jpg

I would like the surface of this 'O' letter i'm working on to look the same way the other letters I have created.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: hello, it would help if you shared the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=rgzrg0PL" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/rgzrg0PL/) there is some problems with the topology and I don't know how to fix it. I want the corner of the inner bevel to look like the one on the outer edge, curving outward instead of inward.

Comment: I managed to fix it, I had to flip the normals.